# Merge Array of Objects by Same Key-Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like so:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Blah",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Foo",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bar",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Blah",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "This is a description"
  }
]
```

I'd like to run some kind of function to combine the objects with the same name in a `description1 + "\n" + description2` pattern, so the end result is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Foo",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bar",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Blah",
    "description": "This is a description\nThis is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "This is a description"
  }
]
```

The order of the array doesn't need to be preserved. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Searched and researched, check. No similar question existed. Summed up question with one middle sentence, plus two properly-formatted before and after examples. No spelling, grammar, or punctuation errors. Title sums up problem without too much detail. Introduced problem, check. Helped others reproduce, check. Added relevant tags, check. Proofread, check. Respond to answers, check. The only code missing was the solution that I didn't have. I'll keep trying to improve my question-asking form, thanks.

Comment: @xd1936 You got my and Robidu's responses because your question shows 0 effort, 0 research - it just asks for help. When you've done research and tried things, include them! You will get much better responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Array.reduce()` to create a map, grouped by name and `Object.values()` on the map will give your the desired result:

```js
let arr = [ { "name": "Blah", "description": "This is a description" }, { "name": "Foo", "description": "This is a description" }, { "name": "Bar", "description": "This is a description" }, { "name": "Blah", "description": "This is a description" }, { "name": "Test", "description": "This is a description" } ];
let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {name,description})=>{
  if(a[name])
    a[name].description += "\n" + description;
   else
    a[name] = Object.assign({},{name,description});
   return a;
},{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the response. Works great with EMCAScript 2015 and above because of `Object.assign()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup object to find duplicates:

```
 const result = [], hash = {};
 for(const {name, description} of input) {
    if(hash[name]) {
      hash[name].description += "\n" + description;
    } else {
      result.push(hash[name] = { name, description });
   }
 }
```

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea you could do a `for...of` in this capacity. Very clever! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and findIndex to check if the new array have any object where the name matches. If it so then update the description

```js
let orgArray = [{
    "name": "Blah",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Foo",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bar",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Blah",
    "description": "This is a description"
  },
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "This is a description"
  }
]

let newArray = orgArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIndexs = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.name === curr.name;

  })
  if (findIndexs === -1) {
    let obj = {
      name: curr.name,
      description: curr.description
    }
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[findIndexs].description = acc[findIndexs].description + ' \n ' + curr.description
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newArray)
```